# Как выбрать объект

Tags: php

Есть объекты хранятся они в $lt->images; если так  `var_dump($lt->images);` получаю так.

```
[0]=>   object(Image) {
    ["id"]=>       int(15)          
    ["for_home"]=>       int(1)     }     
[1]=>   object(Image){    
    ["id"]=>       int(1693)           
    ["for_home"]=>       NULL     } 
[2]=>   object(Image) {     
    ["id"]=>       int(1694)         
    ["for_home"]=>       NULL    }  
[3]=>   object(Image) {     
    ["id"]=>       int(1695)                
    ["for_home"]=>       NULL     }     
[4]=>   object(Image){           
    ["id"]=>       int(1696)               
    ["for_home"]=>       NULL     }
```

пытаюсь получить объект у которого for_home=1 так

```
foreach($lt->images as $image); 
     if($image->for_home==1) {
       echo('yes');
    }
```

и конечно же ни чего не получаю объясните как правильно получить объект  у которого for_home=1

Comment: Попробуйте  так: `$image['for_home']==1`

Comment: с конструкцией все в поряден

Comment: Ошибки какие-нибудь выводятся или просто скрипт ничего не выводит?

Comment: А можно сам `$lt->images` в вопрос? И почему `);` после foreach?

Comment: Обратите внимание на регистр

Comment: Заменить `foreach($lt->images as $image);` на `foreach($lt as $image)`.

Comment: @Rikaz $lt->images по факту верхняя часть это var_dump($lt->images);

Comment: @Etki исправил.

Comment: @cheops ни чего не выводит в if не попадаю

Comment: @Doofy верхний код по факту (с небольшими изменениями это и есть) var_dump($lt->images); с этим ); опечатка исправил уже.

Comment: @Visman $lt другой объект там связи работают определенные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// для примера через json_encode/decode приобразовываем массив в объект
$object = json_decode(json_encode(array(
            'images' => array(
                array('id' => 15, 'for_home' => 1),
                array('id' => 1693, 'for_home' => NULL),
                array('id' => 1694, 'for_home' => NULL),
                array('id' => 1695, 'for_home' => NULL),
                array('id' => 1696, 'for_home' => NULL),
            ))
          ), FALSE);

$for_home = array_filter($object->images, function($item) {
    return $item->for_home !== NULL;
});

print_r($for_home);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [for_home] => 1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

foreach почему-то `foreach($lt->images as $image);` начинается с `;`, вместо `{`

```
$lt = (object) array('images' => array(
    (object) array('id' => 15, 'for_home' => 1),
    (object) array('id' => 1693, 'for_home' => NULL),
    (object) array('id' => 1694, 'for_home' => NULL),
    (object) array('id' => 1695, 'for_home' => NULL),
    (object) array('id' => 1696, 'for_home' => NULL),
));

foreach($lt->images as $image) {
    if($image->for_home == 1) {
        echo('yes');
    }
}
```

Comment: Да это как рас пример не соблюдения, какого либо coding style, так допустим в zend coding style рекомендуеться всегда и везде раставлять `{}`...

Comment: Я не знаю почему у автора получилось `object(Image)`, ждём экспертов

Comment: Я думаю у него какая то реализация коллекции объектов Image

Comment: @Naumov, С самого начала у него была какая-то реализация и он её придерживался

Comment: @Doofy вам нужен полностью объект yiifraimwork 2 ? это просто что бы понятно было?

Comment: @Sergalas, не пользуюсь фреймворками. Нужно добавить метку к вопросу `yii`

Comment: @Doofy вы увидели тут yii я полностью код из него исключил просто вывел свойства объекта как массив и все.

Comment: Я не видел тут yii и совершенно с ним не знаком

Comment: @Naumov, причем тут "coding style"?!

Comment: @uorypm так если бы придерживаться coding style то так `foreach($lt->images as $image);` не напишишь, а напишишь так `foreach($lt->images as $image){ //operators }` и собственно нет ошибки. Вот и говорю яркий пример.

Comment: @Naumov я просто опечатался здесь когда писал или все сюда на 100% живой код вставляют ?

Comment: @Sergalas как минимум просто копируют и вставляют заменяя ссылки и пароли на sample и т.д. Просто одна опечатка и у людей мысли о том что ошибка именно в ней. А не там где то в коде у вас.